# Trying to construct a variable name from a string and another variable name with window[] but not working

Tags: javascript

This is my code:

```js
function test(tlm) { 
 var soundtimer = 'success';
 var type = tlm.replace('send','');
 var timer = window[type+'timer'];

 console.log(timer);
}

test('sendsound');
```

I should get `success` but I get undefined instead. Why is that?

Comment: Your variable 'soundtimer' is scoped to the test function.

Answer (score 1):

Your 'soundtimer' variable is locally scoped to the test function. Moving it outside allows it to be globally declared on window:

```js
var soundtimer = 'success';
function test(tlm) {
  var type = tlm.replace('send','');
  var timer = window[type+'timer'];

  console.log(timer);
}

test('sendsound');
```

Comment: its funny but this is how I have it on my actual code but it wont work regardless.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an object within your function.

```js
function test(tlm) { 
  var local = {
    soundtimer:'success'
  };
 var type = tlm.replace('send','');
 var timer = local[type+'timer'];

 console.log(timer);
}

test('sendsound');
```

Comment: this is good, however I have multiple variables ending with `timer` so I would have to add them all to the object?

Comment: Yes, you can absolutely do that.